# Maximum increasing difference

Tags: java, max, time-complexity

I need to find the maximum increasing distance or difference between numbers in a vector. For example, in the vector `[10, 5, 20, 45, 5, 5, 7]` on first pass it looks that the difference between 10 and 45 is maximum. But on the second iteration the difference between 5 and 45 is larger, so it should be chosen by the algorithm.

I have a solution but it is O(n^2) and for the life of me I can't figure out if there is a solution with lower computational complexity.

```
public void maxDistance(int inputArray[]) {
    int trueMaxValue = 0,   trueMinIndex = 0,   trueMaxIndex = 0,  tempMaxValue;

    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length - 1; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < inputArray.length; ++j) {
            tempMaxValue = inputArray[j] - inputArray[i];
            if (tempMaxValue > trueMaxValue) {
                trueMaxValue = tempMaxValue;
                trueMinIndex = i;
                trueMaxIndex = j;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also need to know which two numbers in the array were used in the max. Can you please help? I just don't know if I should continue to think about it or O(n^2) is the best that you can do?

Comment: Please clarify: what is the expected **output** of this method? You are giving an example, and I conclude: the result should be 40. (delta between 45 and 5).

Comment: The output will be the maximum difference and the location (indices) of the two numbers contributing the that maximum.

Comment: I think the question, as it stands, is open to interpretation. What's the expected output for `[10, 5, 50]`?

Comment: Still a good question for a newbie :-)

Comment: The expected output for `[10, 5, 50]` is 50 - 5, or 45. To further clarify, if the array was `[10, 50, 5]` then the output should be 50 - 10, or 40, because as I wrote in my original post it must be an **increasing difference** and in this case from 50 to 5 is decreasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in O(n) Stephany. You need to add a few variables to remember what is the current best solution. Using your current naming convention you can do the following:

```
    public void maxDistance(int inputArray[]) {
        int currentMin = inputArray[0],     currentMinIndex = 0;
        int trueMaxValue = 0,   trueMinIndex = 0,   trueMaxIndex = 0;
        int tempMaxValue;

        int i = 1;
        while (i < inputArray.length) {
            tempMaxValue = inputArray[i] - inputArray[currentMinIndex];
            if (tempMaxValue > trueMaxValue) {
                trueMaxValue = tempMaxValue;
                trueMinIndex = currentMinIndex;
                trueMaxIndex = i;
            }

            if (inputArray[i] < currentMin) {
                currentMinIndex = i;
                currentMin = inputArray[i];
            }

            ++i;
        }
```

Comment: There was a more effective answer below...  There were three, actually.

Comment: This answer is exceptionally slower.  This method in testing, scaling from 10 ints to 10 million, takes twice the time to run.

Comment: I'll be happy to share my test results after another run
Regardless, yours is still slower. Answer was edited, because you were correct, min should not have started at 0.

Comment: Addressing @anomeric comment: First of all pedagogy is also important and I deliberately decided to use code flow that was as close as possible to how the question was written. Second, I thought that your claim for performance was interesting so I gave it a try and in all runs you are incorrect. The largest difference in run time on 1 million integers was 1 ms (7 and 6 ms). The largest difference on 10 million was 3 ms (16 and 13 ms). Lastly and most importantly your code does not work at all because 'min' never gets updated.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am missing something but:

- iterate the array
- determine the smallest entry
- determine the biggest entry
- compute the delta (max - min)

All of that can be done in one iteration. This would find 5 and 45 and give a difference of 40. And as said - one pass only.

Comment: I came here to say the same thing. I think the max-min works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in linear time.

Here is an outline:

1. Iterate over the array, keeping track of the smallest number seen
   thus far.
2. Compute the difference between the smallest number seen thus far and the current number, and keep track of the largest such difference.

Voilà.

Comment: @GhostCat: The voting patterns can indeed be a bit odd. If I were to guess, I'd imagine that it has to do with you and I solving two different problems. Whoever downvoted your answer might have felt that your interpretation of the question was incorrect. That's just my guess, however. I've asked the OP to clarify the question.

Comment: @GhostCat: I wouldn't read too much into it. We try to help, but if people choose to downvote without the courtesy of a comment, we just have accept it and move on. That's my philosophy anyway.

Comment: True. New day New questions.

Answer (score 1):

You've definitely got better options.  I'm not sure why a nested loop was even necessary here.  I'll edit to include the indices, but I'm not sure why that's helpful in the case scenario considering your array can have duplicate numbers.

```
int[] inputArray = new int[] {10,5,20,5,5,46,7};
int max = 0;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
    max = inputArray[i] > max ? inputArray[i] : max;
    min = inputArray[i] < min ? inputArray[i] : min;
}
int delta = max - min;
```

I'll edit to include the indices, but I'm not sure why that's helpful in the case scenario considering your array can have duplicate numbers.

```
int[] inputArray = new int[] {10,5,20,5,5,46,7};
int max = 0;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int maxIndex = -1;
int minIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
    if (inputArray[i] > max) {
        max = inputArray[i];
        maxIndex = i;
    } 
    if (inputArray[i] < min) {
        min = inputArray[i];
        minIndex = i;
    }
}
int delta = max - min;
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution does not remember the indices. I also don't like ternary operators. I find that they lead to unclear code.

Comment: This code does not work, why don't you test before posting? The variable 'min' will never get updated.

Comment: I'm really sorry and I hope that you do not take this the wrong way. I'm just think that posted code should be correct. But you still have a bug. The correct statement is 'Integer.MAX_VALUE'. I'll be happy to vote you up after you post a correct solution.

Comment: I tried to run your most recent code and it does not work. I think that your loop does not take into account the last element of the array.